# Jira cloud Login with Postman

Tags: authentication, automation, postman, jira

I am practicing automation API testing with Jira Cloud and thinking about some end-to-end scenarios that I can automate. For this purpose, I want to start with the Login functionality by sending a login request via Postman. If I manage to do it with Postman correctly, I will be able to automate it after that. I read a lot about this but I couldn't find an up-to-date way so I will really appreciate any help.

I am searching for something like:

```
POST /rest/auth/1/session
```

Request

EXAMPLE

```
{
    "username": "fred",
    "password": "freds_password"
}
```

But as long as I know, this is from the old documentation, the endpoint is deprecated and I am not able to use it anymore.

Is there a new way to test the Login functionality via Postman?
I know how to authenticate requests to Jira Cloud using Basic Authentication but I just want to create a request to a Login endpoint and check if the Login is successful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The dicumentation is:

[Jira CLoud Authentication](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/intro/#authentication)

https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/software/rest/intro/#introduction

> For personal scripts, bots, and ad-hoc execution of the REST APIs use basic authentication. See Basic auth for REST APIs for details.

If the purpsoe is just to check the authentication with first request, you can use HEAD HTTP request with basic auth.